# How to explode an Array and create a view in Hive?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, presto

I have the following data where `id` is an Integer and `vectors` is an array:

```
id, vectors
1, [1,2,3]
2, [2,3,4]
3, [3,4,5]
```

I would like to explode the `vectors` column with its index postioning such that it looks like this:

```
+---+-----+------+
|id |index|vector|
+---+-----+------+
|1  |0    |1     |
|1  |1    |2     |
|1  |2    |3     |
|2  |0    |2     |
|2  |1    |3     |
|2  |2    |4     |
|3  |0    |3     |
|3  |1    |4     |
|3  |2    |5     |
+---+-----+------+
```

I figured that I can do this using Spark Scala using `selectExpr`

`df.selectExpr("*", "posexplode(vectors) as (index, vector)")`

However, this is a relatively simple task and I would like to avoid writing ETL scripts and was thinking if there is anyway the expression can be used and creating a view for easy access through Presto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to do in Presto using standard SQL syntax with [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
WITH data(id, vector) AS (
    VALUES
    (1, array[1,2,3]),
    (2, array[2,3,4]),
    (3, array[3,4,5])
)
SELECT id, index - 1 AS index, value
FROM data, UNNEST(vector) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(value, index)
```

Note that the index produced by `WITH ORDINALITY` is 1-based, so I subtracted 1 from it to produce the output you included in your question.

Comment: This is amazing. You saved me hours of writing another DAG for post-processing -- Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lateral view` of `Hive` to `explode` array data.
Try below query -

```
select
    id, (row_number() over (partition by id order by col)) -1 as `index`, col as vector
from (
    select 1 as id, array(1,2,3) as vectors from (select '1') t1 union all
    select 2 as id, array(2,3,4) as vectors from (select '1') t2 union all
    select 3 as id, array(3,4,5) as vectors from (select '1') t3
  ) t
LATERAL VIEW explode(vectors) v;
```